# js send post request if user reloads/redirect page

Tags: javascript, http-post

In my project I collect statistics about users but if he click some link in page and this page opened in current page my post request is interrupted.

Maybe exists some "hacks" for send request, but just with use JS and not some else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you asked for hacks,

If it is possible, just add a `target="_blank"` on anchor tags to open the clicked resource so that it opens up in new tab instead of the existing.

If opening a new link via a js function, use `window.open` instead to avoid opening in current window.

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but I need all scenarios, and problems with open page in current page.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like AJAX, sending the post in any asyncronous way.

You have more info in this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: I know how build request I need send request if user close or reload or redirect in current page. It is problems because js code dead if user close page and post request not yet finished.